# Qt Form and main.cpp communication

Tags: qt

i have a Qt project with mainwindow (GUI Application)
how can i communicate with my main via my form?
for example

increase variable (which there's in my main) while button a click in my form

i have make a project in C which its in console application. works fine, and now i make another project which contains ui form with same code. and i want to make communication between form and main function

Comment: Use dependency injection pattern

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variable in Qt, how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471764/global-variable-in-qt-how-to)

Comment: Check out http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/examples-widgets.html (for example the calculator example might be good for you).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Qt signal/slot functionality.

Example:

```
// on mainwindow.cpp. Delcare onButtonClicked as a slot() on the header
void onButtonClicked()
{
    ++myVar;
}

connect(myButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonClicked());
```

[Reference docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: Omg. Who voting this up? It is a great overhead to use slots to transfer values between two objects.

Comment: "increase variable (which there's in my main) while button a click in my form". The proper way to implement this is  by using signals / slots.

Comment: It is possible way, but not proper way.