# Loading Qt resources via QResource::registerResource in a static library

Tags: qt

I'm dynamically loading a Qt `rcc` file using the `QResource::registerResource` API.  When I try to create a `QResource` object - it works fine (`isValid` returns true), but, the size of the object is something ridiculous (500 MB or so) - even though the original image is just about 4KB.

I suspect this is happening because I'm doing this in a static library that is linked in with the main application.  Since this is an external `.rcc` file created by the resource compiler - I cannot use the `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` trick I've seen others propose.

Has anyone ever gotten this to work?  What am I missing?  I'd appreciate any pointers/thoughts.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392863/initializing-qt-resources-embedded-in-static-library